# Train a Keras model to recognize and predict speech in real-time using microphone as audio source

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

Please help me optimize this script. I'm running it in Google Colab GPU runtime. I've implemented many optimizations but they worsened it. I need serious help. I have to submit my project in 3 days!. Let me know if you need additional information. PS: I don't have a Colab subscription. The model is built using Keras.

**What I've tried**

1. Used different optimizers from keras and tensorflow library.
2. Tried using library functions like .cache() and .prefetch() of tensorflow.
3. Tried implementing a CTCLoss function using tensorflow.  Didn't work
4. Applied general best practices

***What I need help with***

1. I want the script to run as fast as possible. Reduce the training time to a minimum.
2. Any refactoring that may help me speedup the training or loading of data.

**Expected results**

1. The script should preprocess the data faster. Possibly stream the data instead of loading it all to memory.
2. Any possible techniques I can apply on the audio files for efficiency and save time on loading them
3. The model should be saved. It should also be loaded to predict the speech in an audio(.wav) file.
4. My main objective is to train a model to recognize and predict speech in real-time using microphone as audio source. Currently, the model is trained in 10 epochs(I've realized it's not enough.
5. The model's first epoch takes around 37-40 mins. All next epochs takes 17-18 minutes. Im using Google Colab's T4 GPU.

> Let me know if you need any additional information that may help. Any small change code will be helpful. If you feel that your tip or suggestion is obvious, please don't hesitate to provide it. It's possible I may have overlooked simple things that are too obvious.

```
%pip install jiwer -q


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display
from jiwer import wer

layers = tf.keras.layers



# DATA_URL = "https://data.keithito.com/data/speech/LJSpeech-1.1.tar.bz2"
# # DATA_PATH = keras.utils.get_file("LJSpeech-1.1", DATA_URL, untar=True)

!wget {DATA_URL}



DATA_PATH="/content/LJSpeech-1.1.tar.bz2"
!tar -xvf {DATA_PATH}



DATA_PATH = "/content/LJSpeech-1.1"
WAVS_PATH = DATA_PATH + "/wavs/"
METADATA_PATH = DATA_PATH + "/metadata.csv"



METADATA_DF = pd.read_csv(METADATA_PATH, sep="|", header=None, quoting=3)



METADATA_DF.head(10)



METADATA_DF.columns = ["file_name", "transcription", "normalized_transcription"]
METADATA_DF = METADATA_DF[["file_name", "normalized_transcription"]]
METADATA_DF = METADATA_DF.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
METADATA_DF.head(3)



split = int(len(METADATA_DF) * 0.90)
DF_TRAIN = METADATA_DF[:split]
DF_VAL = METADATA_DF[split:]

print(f"Size of the training set: {len(DF_TRAIN)}")
print(f"Size of the validation set: {len(DF_VAL)}")



characters = [x for x in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'?! "]
char_to_num = keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=characters, oov_token="")
num_to_char = keras.layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), oov_token="", invert=True
)

print(
    f"The vocabulary is: {char_to_num.get_vocabulary()}"
    f"\n(size= {char_to_num.vocabulary_size()})"
)



char_to_num



frame_length = 256
frame_step = 160
fft_length = 384


def encode_single_sample(wav_file, label):
    # Process Audio
    file = tf.io.read_file(WAVS_PATH + wav_file + ".wav")
    audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(file)
    audio = tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)
    audio = tf.cast(audio, tf.float32)
    spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(
        audio, frame_length=frame_length, frame_step=frame_step, fft_length=fft_length
    )
    spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)
    spectrogram = tf.math.pow(spectrogram, 0.5)
    means = tf.math.reduce_mean(spectrogram, 1, keepdims=True)
    stddevs = tf.math.reduce_std(spectrogram, 1, keepdims=True)
    spectrogram = (spectrogram - means) / (stddevs + 1e-10)
    label = tf.strings.lower(label)
    label = tf.strings.unicode_split(label, input_encoding="UTF-8")
    label = char_to_num(label)
    return spectrogram, label



batch_size = 32
TRAIN_DATASET = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (list(DF_TRAIN["file_name"]), list(DF_TRAIN["normalized_transcription"]))
)
TRAIN_DATASET = (
    TRAIN_DATASET.map(encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    .cache()
    .padded_batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)

VALIDATION_DATASET = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (list(DF_VAL["file_name"]), list(DF_VAL["normalized_transcription"]))
)
VALIDATION_DATASET = (
    VALIDATION_DATASET.map(encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    .cache()
    .padded_batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
for batch in TRAIN_DATASET.take(1):
    spectrogram = batch[0][0].numpy()
    spectrogram = np.array([np.trim_zeros(x) for x in np.transpose(spectrogram)])
    label = batch[1][0]
    label = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(label)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    ax.imshow(spectrogram, vmax=1)
    ax.set_title(label)
    ax.axis("off")
    file = tf.io.read_file(WAVS_PATH + list(DF_TRAIN["file_name"])[0] + ".wav")
    audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(file)
    audio = audio.numpy()
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(audio)
    ax.set_title("Signal Wave")
    ax.set_xlim(0, len(audio))
    display.display(display.Audio(np.transpose(audio), rate=16000))
plt.show()



# def CTCLoss(y_true, y_pred):
#     batch_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
#     input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
#     label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

#     input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_length, 1), dtype="int64")
#     label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_length, 1), dtype="int64")

#     loss = keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
#     return loss


def CTCLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.nn.ctc_loss(y_true, y_pred)



import torch.optim as optim


def build_model(input_dim, output_dim, rnn_layers=5, rnn_units=128):
    input_spectrogram = layers.Input((None, input_dim), name="input")
    x = layers.Reshape((-1, input_dim, 1), name="expand_dim")(input_spectrogram)
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        filters=32,
        kernel_size=[11, 41],
        strides=[2, 2],
        padding="same",
        use_bias=False,
        name="conv_1",
    )(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization(name="conv_1_bn")(x)
    x = layers.ReLU(name="conv_1_relu")(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        filters=32,
        kernel_size=[11, 21],
        strides=[1, 2],
        padding="same",
        use_bias=False,
        name="conv_2",
    )(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization(name="conv_2_bn")(x)
    x = layers.ReLU(name="conv_2_relu")(x)
    x = layers.Reshape((-1, x.shape[-2] * x.shape[-1]))(x)
    for i in range(1, rnn_layers + 1):
        recurrent = layers.GRU(
            units=rnn_units,
            activation="tanh",
            recurrent_activation="sigmoid",
            use_bias=True,
            return_sequences=True,
            reset_after=True,
            name=f"gru_{i}",
        )
        x = layers.Bidirectional(
            recurrent, name=f"bidirectional_{i}", merge_mode="concat"
        )(x)
        if i < rnn_layers:
            x = layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)(x)
    x = layers.Dense(units=rnn_units * 2, name="dense_1")(x)
    x = layers.ReLU(name="dense_1_relu")(x)
    output = layers.Dense(units=output_dim + 1, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = keras.Model(input_spectrogram, output, name="AutoSpeech")
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
    # optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=CTCLoss)
    return model



model = build_model(
    input_dim=fft_length // 2 + 1,
    output_dim=char_to_num.vocabulary_size(),
    rnn_units=512,
)
model.summary(line_length=110)



def decode_batch_predictions(pred):
    input_length = np.ones(pred.shape[0]) * pred.shape[1]
    results = keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_length, greedy=True)[0][
        0
    ]
    output_text = []
    for result in results:
        result = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(result)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        output_text.append(result)
    return output_text


class CallbackEval(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, dataset):
        super().__init__()
        self.dataset = dataset

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch: int, logs=None):
        predictions = []
        targets = []
        for batch in self.dataset:
            X, y = batch
            batch_predictions = model.predict(X)
            batch_predictions = decode_batch_predictions(batch_predictions)
            predictions.extend(batch_predictions)
            for label in y:
                label = (
                    tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(label)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
                )
                targets.append(label)
        wer_score = wer(targets, predictions)
        print("-" * 100)
        print(f"Word Error Rate: {wer_score:.4f}")
        print("-" * 100)
        for i in np.random.randint(0, len(predictions), 2):
            print(f"Target: {targets[i]}")
            print(f"Prediction: {predictions[i]}")
            print("-" * 100)



epochs = 10
validation_callback = CallbackEval(VALIDATION_DATASET)

history = model.fit(
    TRAIN_DATASET,
    validation_data=VALIDATION_DATASET,
    steps_per_epoch=len(DF_TRAIN) // batch_size,
    validation_steps=len(DF_VAL) // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[validation_callback],
)



predictions = []
targets = []
for batch in VALIDATION_DATASET:
    X, y = batch
    batch_predictions = model.predict(X)
    batch_predictions = decode_batch_predictions(batch_predictions)
    predictions.extend(batch_predictions)
    for label in y:
        label = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(label)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        targets.append(label)
    wer_score = wer(targets, predictions)
    print("-" * 100)
    print(f"Word Error Rate: {wer_score:.4f}")
    print("-" * 100)
    for i in np.random.randint(0, len(predictions), 2):
        print(f"Target: {targets[i]}")
        print(f"Prediction: {predictions[i]}")
        print("-" * 100)
```

---

***NOTE:***  I am using the [Keithito LJ-Speech Dataset](https://keithito.com/LJ-Speech-Dataset/) to train the Keras model

---

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To help reviewers give you better answers, we need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*.  Please add sufficient context to your question to describe the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  Also, [edit] the **title** to simply [**summarise the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: Let me know if I am missing out on providing some important information about the code or my objective. I am constantly checking the question post.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the tip. I will be posting more questions. I will be careful to keep in mind your suggestions. 

Comment: Advice: Heed the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings).

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for the tip. I've read the style guide and refactored and formatted my code accordingly. Sad to say it didn't improve the script, but.. I've learned a lot about styling and indentation. Thanks again 